# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
 private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string costring = connection();
            string MyQuery = "select expense from dbo.KmtAccounts where date between '"+ txtFromDate +"' and '" +txtToDate +"' and    registernumber='" + txtRegNo.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(costring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MyQuery, conn);
            conn.Open();
            txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Don't build up your queries like that. Use parameterised queries and declare the parameters of the correct datatype. Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: What are the values of your variables? They can depend on culture. BTW: Don't you afraid of SQL injection?

Comment: Whats your question?You post only code and title!

Comment: Nice article that shows the dangers of vulnerability to SQL injection: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html.

Comment: Thank you all for the advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several point to improve within your code.

1. It seems that **txtFromDate and txtToDate are controls?!** I think you'd like to access txtFromDate.Text
2. You should really make use of **[SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to prevent SQL injection** (good example at [dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter))
3. You may check if your UI values are correct with some kind of validation or even better, choose a **control that only allows valid values** (*[DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=lgNHUMCWAYnm4QThy4CQDw&usg=AFQjCNF7DRZ_LbEsWe00EWbhN5Sf9yBliQ&sig2=QsRXhaqKey9nKlWX7ObD8Q), ...*)

Comment: but i got the result when i run the query select sum(expense) from dbo.KmtAccounts where date between '05/23/12'  and '05/30/12' and    registernumber='kl08347'

Comment: so txtFromDate is a **string value** _not a control_ - check for point 1. what about **sql injection (2)** and **controls (3)**? try to enter `'05/23/12'; delete from dbo.KmtAccounts;--'` and think about what will happen!

Comment: now am using monthcalendar instead of textbox but how we get the selected date, which property of monthcalendar should used? Can you help me?

Comment: i mean in code  string MyQuery = "select expense from dbo.KmtAccounts where date between '"+monthcalendar1.???? +"' and '" +monthcalendar2.???+"' and    registernumber='" + txtRegNo.Text + "'";

Comment: a [monthCalendar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.aspx) may select a range (_SelectionStart , -End_). you may use it with **SelectionStart** (returns a dateTime) or change your code to make use of a [jquery UI dateTimePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: problem is solved now. will sql injection matters in a windows application?

Comment: sqlInjection will matter in any application you dynamically change a database!

Comment: ok.. then i will try to recode and let you know. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue causing the exception is that the value in `txtFromDate` and/or `txtToDate` isn't understood as representing a date.

The bigger issue is that there seems to be little or nothing to prevent one of those values containing a valid value followed by `';delete from dbo.KmtAccounts;---`.

Both problems will be solved by making the query `select expense from dbo.KmtAccounts where date between @from and @to and    registernumber=@reg` and then using parameters to add the dates (as dates, not as strings) and reg-number into the query.